# Animate high svg in powerpoint

Tags: svg, jquery-animate, powerpoint

I've got a very high svg-file which I want to be animated like an outro in a movie in Powerpoint.

Do you know any way how to manage this?

Greeting

Answer (score 0):

Solved spontaneously right now:

I exported it from Illustrator with a high quality jpg and disabled picture compression in powerpoint.